# Checkout files from a specific commit failed with space in the path

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

What I want to achieve is to get all updates of a specific commit 76363636 from branch1 to branch2.

I used following codes instead of just checkout this commit, as it does not fit my purpose :

```
git checkout branch1 $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 76363636)
```

This work fine when the file path in the commit does not have space in between. I used this code several times.

But not when there is space in one the file path , ex. below :

> force-app/main/default/layouts/PersonAccount-Layout
> Professionnel.layout-meta.xml

I get following error :

> *error: pathspec 'force-app/main/default/layouts/PersonAccount-Layout' did not match any file(s) known to git*

How to actually protect the file with double quote as I am getting the files dynamically

The below code won't work :

```
git checkout branch1 "$(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 76363636)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You want to set `IFS` temporarily while running the command:

```
save="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'    # depends on shell
git checkout branch1 $(git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 76363636)
IFS="$save"
```

or similar.  You may have to use something other than `$'\n'` here.  You might also consider using `git restore` rather than `git checkout`.  See all the details below.

#### Long

This isn't a problem with *Git*—well, not exactly—but rather with the *shell you're using*.  The fix is either to get the shell to behave better, or to bypass it entirely (see the `git restore` section below).

When you enter a command at the command prompt:

```
$ command with some arguments
```

it is the *shell*—the command-line interpreter—that breaks up the pieces here: <kbd>command</kbd>, <kbd>with</kbd>, <kbd>some</kbd>, and <kbd>arguments</kbd> each become a "word", and the shell then finds some executable somewhere on the system that is named `command` and runs it with all four "words" provided as four separate `argv` arguments.  The `argv[0]` argument is typically either ignored entirely, or used to augment error messages in case the command is installed under a different name than expected (e.g., `git-2.17` to run an old version of Git).  The remaining arguments, in `argv[1]` through `argv[3]` inclusive in this case, are then interpreted by the program—but note that they have been *pre-divided*.

Should you wish to run, e.g.,

```
$ git restore --source=HEAD -SW "file with spaces"
```

you *must* use quotes (double or single) so that the shell invokes <kbd>git</kbd> with arguments <kbd>restore</kbd>, <kbd>--source=HEAD</kbd>, <kbd>-SW</kbd>, and <kbd>file with spaces</kbd>.  Note how the enclosing quotes have vanished but the spaces are retained: there's a single argument containing two blanks.

The command:

```
git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r 76363636
```

itself is broken into six words, beginning with <kbd>git</kbd> and ending with <kbd>76363636</kbd>.  The shell runs that command and—because the command as a whole was enclosed in `$(...)`—*reads its output*.  The shell then *interprets its output as a series of words*, separated by white space: spaces, tabs, and newlines.  The shell breaks up those words, and then run:

```
git checkout branch1 <word1> <word2> ... <wordN>
```

for all N broken-apart words.

Since it's the *shell* that is doing the breaking-up, it is the *shell* that you must overcome here.  There is a way to do this.

#### The shell breaks words using `$IFS`

Bourne-derived shells use the *internal field separator* variable, `$IFS`, to determine what makes something a "word".  The default IFS setting is space-tab-newline.  This is a bit tricky to show, since space, tab, and newline all *display* as blanks or nothings on your screen.

To *represent* space, tab, and newline, we can use a literal space in quotes, the sequence `\t` for <kbd>TAB</kbd>, and the sequence `\n` for <kbd>NL</kbd> (newline).  *Some* shells let you do this directly:

```
var=$' \t\n'
```

That's a single quote, preceded by a dollar-sign `$` character: the text inside is then interpreted with backslash sequences handled similarly to their usage in the C programming language.

Some versions of the shell do not allow this; here, we can use the POSIX `printf` command:

```
printf " \t\n"
```

(here, either double or single quotes suffice).

What we *want*, of course, is for the shell to break only at newlines.  Should you have files whose names contain embedded newlines, this won't work—but such file names are particularly evil and don't seem to be in common use, unlike Windows and macOS file names that do commonly have embedded spaces in them.  If you're really aiming for bullet-proofing, you would want the `-z` option and NUL-terminated paths: ASCII NULs are the only character literally forbidden in pathnames on Linux (and hence in Git as well).

Having had the shell break our path names up at newlines, we should—for "shell hygiene" if nothing else—*restore* the `$IFS` setting afterward.  For that, we can either set `IFS` back to space-tab-newline literally:

```
IFS=$'\n'
... do things using $(...) ...
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

Or, we can grab the *current* setting, set it to what we need, and then *restore the old setting*.  This is nice for other users who may have set IFS for *their* purposes and don't want us destroying it:

```
f() {
    local save
    save="$IFS"
    IFS=$(printf '\n')
    ... our code ...
    IFS="$save"
}
```

Function `f` can now be called safely from some other shell function that *also* changes `IFS` temporarily, without having to keep setting `IFS` in this other shell function.

(Here, I've used `printf` instead of `$'...'`, in case we have a shell that does not allow the `$'...'` usage.)

#### Using `git restore`

The `git checkout` command has a couple of defects here:

- If the list of differences from `git diff-tree` is *empty*, we check out the entire branch.  That's probably not what we want.  This is a very big defect!
- If some of the file names start with `-`, this `git checkout` will behave badly.  We can fix this by adding `--`, which is probably a good idea.
- If `branch1` is not a valid branch name, `git checkout` will behave badly.

We can avoid all of these problems *and* solve the entire `IFS`-related problem by using `git restore` with its `--pathspec-from-file` and `--pathspec-file-nul` flags.  (Be sure your Git version of `git restore` supports these flags; they first appeared in Git 2.25, while `git restore` itself first appeared in Git 2.23.)  The `-z` flag in `git diff-tree` has been there far longer, so if your Git is at least 2.25 you have both.

What we do, then, is this:

```
git diff-tree <options> -z <rev> |
git --literal-pathspecs restore --source=branch1 --pathspec-from-file=- --pathspec-file-nul
```

The `git diff-tree` runs as usual but this time outputs *un-encoded* path names—this solves a number of problems you have not yet encountered—and terminates each pathname with an ASCII NUL.  The `git restore` command then *reads* these pathnames (as pathspecs) from standard input.  The `--literal-pathspecs` option to `git` itself tells `git restore` not to try to interpret pathspec magic in any of the input paths.

Comment: wow this is a long answer, but very interesting. Will try it and let you know.

Comment: Yes this is what i needed. Thanks man!